# Location of mongodb.conf file in meteor framework

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoimport

I am using meteor framework for an application. In that I want to import a file in mongodb (default db of this framework). When I am using mongoimport command,it is showing following error "couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1". I am using following command

```
mongoimport  --type csv --file data.csv --headerline
```

After googling, could find that, there is a need to remove mongodb.lock file. The location of this file is in project-> .meteor-> local-> db -> mongodb.lock.

But need to repair mongodb.conf file but unable to search that in the project.

Any pointers please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is actually your problem.

What is more likely is that you are running a local project with `meteor run` but now you are trying to connect to that `mongod` instance using `mongoimport`. But the problem here is the instance your project is using is not using the default port that MongoDB usually does. This is normal.

Find your actual running instance for your project from the command line, so from Unix based systems (as an example):

```
ps aux | grep mongod
111        778  0.3  0.8 704720 16720 ?        Ssl  May16  28:20 ./usr/bin/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent -conf /etc/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.config
mongodb    909  3.3 31.7 8589628 650648 ?      Ssl  May16 262:21 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
neillunn 18720  3.2  2.0 631848 41328 pts/1    Sl+  21:25   0:02 /home/neillunn/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --nohttpinterface --port 3002 --dbpath /home/neillunn/projects/neilproject/.meteor/local/db --oplogSize 8 --replSet meteor
```

neillunn 19282  0.0  0.0   9396   916 pts/2    S+   21:26   0:00 grep mongod

And we can see that the **second** process is our meteor project instance running on port `3002'. So what you want to do is connect to that:

```
mongoimport --port 3002 <other options>
```

And now you are using the correct port then everything is okay.

Verify your connection using the `mongo` command shell with the same `--port` option.

**BTW**: Pretty much as shown, default instance running for meteor does not use a "mongodb.conf" file.

Comment: The output of the grep command is as follows:                     priya@Wind1:~/gbproject$ ps aux | grep mongod
root      3021  0.0  0.3  52768 10452 pts/2    Sl+  11:34   0:00 /home/priya/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/mongodb/bin/mongo 127.0.0.1:3002/meteor
                        priya     3399  0.0  0.0   4388   828 pts/1    S+   13:44   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod
                       priya@Wind1:~/gbproject$ mongoimport --port 3002  --file data.csv
couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1:3002] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:3002
Where  I am doing wrong?. Please let me know

Comment: @priya You do not actually seem to be running a `mongod` process. Either have your project running or use the `--dbpath` option for a process that is not running.

Comment: @Neil.... means you are saying that in one console, I need to run project using meteor run and in another console, This mongoimport command should be run....

Comment: @priya You either need that `mongod` instance from your project running or use the [`--dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--dbpath) option from mongoimport which allows you to do this when the `mongod` instance is not running.

Comment: Question... if the default instance for meteor does not have a config file, how is it possible to connect to this instance of Mongo from an external source?

Comment: @JoePrivett You do not need a config file to run a mongod instance as all options can be specified on the command line, much as meteor does by default. You seem to be asking here in relation to one of your own questions, or at least if you have a different question to the one that is asked then you should post that question.